# How can I create a website summary with Perl?

Tags: perl

When you share something on Facebook or Digg, it generates some summary of the page.  How would I do this in Perl?  What algorithms are there?

For example:

If I go to Facebook and tried to share this question as a link:
[How can I create a website summary with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279851/facebook-digg-get-website-summary)

It retrieves "Facebook/Digg get website summary? - Stack Overflow" as the title (which is just the title of the page) and [... incomplete question?]

Comment: Can you explain the kind of summary you are looking for in more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) is your friend.

Some promising looking modules:

- [HTML::Summary](http://search.cpan.org/~tgrose/HTML-Summary-0.017/lib/HTML/Summary.pm)
- [HTML::SummaryBasic](http://search.cpan.org/~lgoddard/HTML-SummaryBasic-0.1/SummaryBasic.pm)
- [Lingua::EN::Summarize](http://search.cpan.org/~fimm/Lingua-EN-Summarize-0.2/Summarize.pm)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean sharing a link...

Usually the summary is written by the user submitting the URL. If you have to write a summary automagically this can be achieved by:

- Using the first 100 or so characters of the document body (in itself not easy)
- Using metadata like the description or keywords (often empty or spammed)
- Context-relevant summaries like [recreating Google snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195947/1201464#1201464) (sorry its PHP but simple)
- Tags/keywords from the document using something like the [Yahoo Keyword Extractor API](http://search.cpan.org/~sock/WWW-Yahoo-KeywordExtractor-0.5.2/lib/WWW/Yahoo/KeywordExtractor.pm) or your own keyword density function

Your best bet is to ask the user!

Hope that helps somewhat :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to scrape the URL and find the "most significant paragraph" which might be the first <div> or <p> element after the first <h2> or <h1>, depending on the layout of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could check and see if there is a meta description on the page, but that leaves you at the mercy of whoever wrote the meta description.

Comment: I tried to do this, but most of the articles do not contain them.